# ls -l freezes terminal locally and remotely

Tags: centos, ldap, openldap, strace

I've been reading other SF threads regarding `ls` not returning results or freezing and stalling terminal sessions and it appears they usually the fault of network problems. My problem however, occurs both over remote SSH sessions but also if I am physically at the server itself...

I just installed CentOS 5.4 on one of our servers. I'm setting up some rdiff-backup scripts and when I downloaded librsync and untared it, thats when I started seeing some weird behavior with `ls -l`.

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/librsync/files/librsync/0.9.7/librsync-0.9.7.tar.gz/download /tmp

cd /tmp

tar -xzf librsync-0.9.7.tar.gz
```

Simple enough.  To view the files in this directory I did this:

```
ls
```

results:

```
librsync-0.9.7  librsync-0.9.7.tar.gz
```

Now, if I `ls -l`, my terminal freezes. I have to re-ssh in to keep going. After reading SF threads, I thought it was network related.

So I was extremely surprised to go sit down *at the server itself* and see the *exact same thing happen*... So its obviously not a network issues.

Even if I `ls /tmp/librsync-0.9.7`, my terminal freezes just the same...

Next I did an strace and got this (warning: wall of text coming....):

```
strace ls -l /tmp

execve("/bin/ls", ["ls", "-l", "/tmp"], [/* 21 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1c521000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b8582cc0000
uname({sys="Linux", node="massive.ourdomain.com", ...}) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=71746, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 71746, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x2b8582cc1000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY)     = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \"\200\2730\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=53448, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b8582cd3000
mmap(0x30bb800000, 2132936, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x30bb800000
mprotect(0x30bb807000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x30bba07000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x7000) = 0x30bba07000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libacl.so.1", O_RDONLY)    = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\31@\2740\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=28008, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x30bc400000, 2120992, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x30bc400000
mprotect(0x30bc406000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x30bc605000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x5000) = 0x30bc605000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`E\300\2730\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=95464, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x30bbc00000, 2192784, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x30bbc00000
mprotect(0x30bbc15000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x30bbe15000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x15000) = 0x30bbe15000
mmap(0x30bbe17000, 1424, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x30bbe17000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)      = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220\332\201\2720\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1717800, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b8582cd4000
mmap(0x30ba800000, 3498328, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x30ba800000
mprotect(0x30ba94d000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x30bab4d000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x14d000) = 0x30bab4d000
mmap(0x30bab52000, 16728, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x30bab52000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220W\0\2730\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=145824, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x30bb000000, 2204528, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x30bb000000
mprotect(0x30bb016000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x30bb215000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x15000) = 0x30bb215000
mmap(0x30bb217000, 13168, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x30bb217000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libattr.so.1", O_RDONLY)   = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\17\300\2750\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=17888, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x30bdc00000, 2110728, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x30bdc00000
mprotect(0x30bdc04000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x30bde03000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x30bde03000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY)     = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\20\16\300\2720\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=23360, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b8582cd5000
mmap(0x30bac00000, 2109696, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x30bac00000
mprotect(0x30bac02000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x30bae02000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x30bae02000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libsepol.so.1", O_RDONLY)  = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0=\0\2740\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=247496, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x30bc000000, 2383136, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x30bc000000
mprotect(0x30bc03b000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x30bc23b000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3b000) = 0x30bc23b000
mmap(0x30bc23c000, 40224, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x30bc23c000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b8582cd6000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b8582cd7000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x2b8582cd6c50) = 0
mprotect(0x30bba07000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x30bab4d000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x30bb215000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x30ba61b000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x30bae02000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x2b8582cc1000, 71746)           = 0
set_tid_address(0x2b8582cd6ce0)         = 24102
set_robust_list(0x2b8582cd6cf0, 0x18)   = 0
futex(0x7fff72d02d6c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x30bb005370, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x30bb00e7c0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x30bb0052b0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x30bb00e7c0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=10240*1024, rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY}) = 0
access("/etc/selinux/", F_OK)           = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1c521000
brk(0x1c542000)                         = 0x1c542000
open("/etc/selinux/config", O_RDONLY)   = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=448, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b8582cc1000
read(3, "# This file controls the state o"..., 4096) = 448
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x2b8582cc1000, 4096)            = 0
open("/proc/mounts", O_RDONLY)          = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b8582cc1000
read(3, "rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0\n/dev/root"..., 4096) = 577
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x2b8582cc1000, 4096)            = 0
open("/selinux/mls", O_RDONLY)          = 3
read(3, "1", 19)                        = 1
close(3)                                = 0
socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM, 0)         = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/setrans/.setrans-unix"...}, 110) = 0
sendmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(5)=[{"\1\0\0\0", 4}, {"\1\0\0\0", 4}, {"\1\0\0\0", 4}, {"\0", 1}, {"\0", 1}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 14
readv(3, [{"\1\0\0\0", 4}, {"\1\0\0\0", 4}, {"\0\0\0\0", 4}], 3) = 12
readv(3, [{"\0", 1}], 1)                = 1
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=56413824, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 56413824, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x2b8582cd8000
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=65, ws_col=137, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2528, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b85862a5000
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2528
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x2b85862a5000, 4096)            = 0
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_TIME/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_TIME/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_TIME/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_TIME/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_TIME/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_TIME/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("/tmp", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISVTX|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
getxattr("/tmp", "system.posix_acl_access", 0x0, 0) = -1 ENODATA (No data available)
getxattr("/tmp", "system.posix_acl_default", 0x0, 0) = -1 ENODATA (No data available)
socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM, 0)         = 3
fcntl(3, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/nscd/socket"...}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM, 0)         = 3
fcntl(3, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/nscd/socket"...}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
open("/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY)    = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1711, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b85862a5000
read(3, "#\n# /etc/nsswitch.conf\n#\n# An ex"..., 4096) = 1711
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x2b85862a5000, 4096)            = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=71746, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 71746, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x2b85862a5000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\37\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=53880, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2139432, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x2b85862b7000
mprotect(0x2b85862c1000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x2b85864c0000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x9000) = 0x2b85864c0000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x2b85864c0000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x2b85862a5000, 71746)           = 0
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY)           = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1823, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b85862a5000
read(3, "root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash\n"..., 4096) = 1823
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x2b85862a5000, 4096)            = 0
socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM, 0)         = 3
fcntl(3, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/nscd/socket"...}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM, 0)         = 3
fcntl(3, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/nscd/socket"...}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
open("/etc/group", O_RDONLY)            = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=743, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b85862a5000
read(3, "root:x:0:root\nbin:x:1:root,bin,d"..., 4096) = 743
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x2b85862a5000, 4096)            = 0
open("/tmp", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getdents(3, /* 8 entries */, 32768)     = 264
lstat("/tmp/librsync-0.9.7.tar.gz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=453802, ...}) = 0
getxattr("/tmp/librsync-0.9.7.tar.gz", "system.posix_acl_access", 0x0, 0) = -1 ENODATA (No data available)
getxattr("/tmp/librsync-0.9.7.tar.gz", "system.posix_acl_default", 0x0, 0) = -1 ENODATA (No data available)
lstat("/tmp/librsync-0.9.7", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
getxattr("/tmp/librsync-0.9.7", "system.posix_acl_access", 0x0, 0) = -1 ENODATA (No data available)
getxattr("/tmp/librsync-0.9.7", "system.posix_acl_default", 0x0, 0) = -1 ENODATA (No data available)
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY)           = 4
fcntl(4, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1823, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b85862a5000
read(4, "root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash\n"..., 4096) = 1823
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
munmap(0x2b85862a5000, 4096)            = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=71746, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 71746, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 4, 0) = 0x2b85862a5000
close(4)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libnss_ldap.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\300r\4\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=3169960, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 5329912, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0) = 0x2b85864c2000
mprotect(0x2b858679e000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x2b858699d000, 176128, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0x2db000) = 0x2b858699d000
mmap(0x2b85869c8000, 62456, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b85869c8000
close(4)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libcom_err.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\n\300\2770\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=10000, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x30bfc00000, 2103048, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0) = 0x30bfc00000
mprotect(0x30bfc02000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x30bfe01000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0x1000) = 0x30bfe01000
close(4)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libkeyutils.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`\n@\2760\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=9472, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x30be400000, 2102416, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0) = 0x30be400000
mprotect(0x30be402000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x30be601000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0x1000) = 0x30be601000
close(4)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\2402\0\2760\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=92736, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x30be000000, 2181864, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0) = 0x30be000000
mprotect(0x30be011000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x30be211000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0x11000) = 0x30be211000
mmap(0x30be213000, 6888, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x30be213000
close(4)                                = 0
mprotect(0x30be211000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x2b85862a5000, 71746)           = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {0x1, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x30ba8302d0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
futex(0x2b85869c7708, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
open("/etc/ldap.conf", O_RDONLY)        = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9119, ...}) = 0
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9119, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b85862a5000
read(4, "# @(#)$Id: ldap.conf,v 1.38 2006"..., 4096) = 4096
read(4, "Use the OpenLDAP password change"..., 4096) = 4096
read(4, " OpenLDAP 2.0 and earlier is \"no"..., 4096) = 927
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
munmap(0x2b85862a5000, 4096)            = 0
uname({sys="Linux", node="massive.ourdomain.com", ...}) = 0
open("/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY)      = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=107, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b85862a5000
read(4, "; generated by /sbin/dhclient-sc"..., 4096) = 107
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
munmap(0x2b85862a5000, 4096)            = 0
socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM, 0)         = 4
fcntl(4, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/nscd/socket"...}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(4)                                = 0
socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM, 0)         = 4
fcntl(4, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/nscd/socket"...}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(4)                                = 0
open("/etc/host.conf", O_RDONLY)        = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=17, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b85862a5000
read(4, "order hosts,bind\n", 4096)     = 17
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
munmap(0x2b85862a5000, 4096)            = 0
futex(0x30bab54d44, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY)            = 4
fcntl(4, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=187, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b85862a5000
read(4, "# Do not remove the following li"..., 4096) = 187
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
munmap(0x2b85862a5000, 4096)            = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=71746, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 71746, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 4, 0) = 0x2b85862a5000
close(4)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libnss_dns.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\17\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=23736, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2113792, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0) = 0x2b85869d8000
mprotect(0x2b85869dc000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x2b8586bdb000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0x3000) = 0x2b8586bdb000
close(4)                                = 0
mprotect(0x2b8586bdb000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x2b85862a5000, 71746)           = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.10.20")}, 28) = 0
fcntl(4, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(4, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0
gettimeofday({1276265920, 823870}, NULL) = 0
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLOUT}])
sendto(4, "C\v\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\7massive\10ourdomain\3co"..., 38, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 38
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000)  = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
ioctl(4, FIONREAD, [122])               = 0
recvfrom(4, "C\v\205\200\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\2\7massive\10ourdomain\3co"..., 1024, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.10.20")}, [16]) = 122
close(4)                                = 0
open("/etc/openldap/ldap.conf", O_RDONLY) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=335, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b85862a5000
read(4, "#\n# LDAP Defaults\n#\n\n# See ldap."..., 4096) = 335
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
munmap(0x2b85862a5000, 4096)            = 0
getuid()                                = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
getgid()                                = 0
getegid()                               = 0
open("/root/ldaprc", O_RDONLY)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/root/.ldaprc", O_RDONLY)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/etc/ldap.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9119, ...}) = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
brk(0x1c566000)                         = 0x1c566000
open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY)            = 4
fcntl(4, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=187, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b85862a5000
read(4, "# Do not remove the following li"..., 4096) = 187
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
munmap(0x2b85862a5000, 4096)            = 0
open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY)            = 4
fcntl(4, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=187, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b85862a5000
read(4, "# Do not remove the following li"..., 4096) = 187
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
munmap(0x2b85862a5000, 4096)            = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.10.20")}, 28) = 0
fcntl(4, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(4, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0
gettimeofday({1276265920, 855948}, NULL) = 0
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLOUT}])
sendto(4, "\32 \1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\4ldap\10ourdomain\3com\0\0"..., 35, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 35
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000)  = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
ioctl(4, FIONREAD, [104])               = 0
recvfrom(4, "\32 \205\200\0\1\0\1\0\1\0\0\4ldap\10ourdomain\3com\0\0"..., 1024, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.10.20")}, [16]) = 104
close(4)                                = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.10.20")}, 28) = 0
fcntl(4, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(4, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0
gettimeofday({1276265920, 858536}, NULL) = 0
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLOUT}])
sendto(4, "I\375\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\4ldap\10ourdomain\3com\0\0"..., 35, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 35
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000)  = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
ioctl(4, FIONREAD, [139])               = 0
recvfrom(4, "I\375\205\200\0\1\0\2\0\2\0\2\4ldap\10ourdomain\3com\0\0"..., 1024, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.10.20")}, [16]) = 139
close(4)                                = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
setsockopt(4, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, [1], 4) = 0
setsockopt(4, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
fcntl(4, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(4, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(389), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.20.0.30")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 120000
```

And thats where it stops, right there after that last 120000.... Using strace, I can obviously CTRL+C to keep going. But like I said, normally the terminal completely freezes.

Anyone have any clues?

**UPDATE**

`ls -l > out.txt 2> err.txt` resulting in empty out.txt and err.txt files.

`ls -n` DID return the proper results. So what is it about GID and UID that its having problems with? Is it an LDAP issue like Slobo said? Why would my server try to contact our LDAP server when I list files?

**UPDATE**

The problem was in fact LDAP related as you guys point out. It was a misconfiguration in the LDAP settings. Thanks guys

Comment: Try streaming the output to a file: ls -l > out.txt 2> err.txt

Comment: I am curious if it does this with "ls -n" as well. That tells it to not resolve the GID and UID of the objects, and in turn bypasses the lookup for same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it's contacting ldap server to get accounting information on the extracted files - it untared with UIDs that your system doesn't recognize perhaps. Not sure why it would produce such a stall - check your LDAP server logs?

Comment: I'm also seeing in those logs that you've got different private networks involved (10.x.x.x, 192.168.x.x), perhaps there is a misconfiguration. Anything suspicious in your hosts file?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that ls -n performed normally suggests strongly that the reason ls -l is hanging is because it is failing to translate UID and GID numbers into Users and Groups. Resolving those is configured by the '[name service switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch)'. This is (usually) configured by the /etc/nsswitch.conf file. Something on either the 'passwd' or 'groups' line is failing to return information for UID or GID. You can isolate which it might be by temporarily removing methods from the appropriate lines.

Since this is a tarball you're expanding, it is entirely likely that the tarball had some UID/GID on files that you don't have in your system, so it is taking a long time to fail out. If you don't need those, or just want to get your archive working, you can try adding a few options to the extract command:

```
tar --owner=yourname --group=users -xvf archive.tar
```

This will force ownership of the extracted files to known-good values, which should in turn allow ls -l to complete in a reasonable time.